# How do I set Netbeans as the default for .js files

Tags: netbeans, default-programs, javascript

I have `Netbeans 8.1` installed on my computer and works well as the default for `php` and `css` files but can't set it as the default editor for `javascript` files. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on any .js files and select "properties" option and in "properties" dialog box, go to "open with" tab and select netbeans from there and if netbeans is not listed there, go to "add" button and show the location of netbeans and set it as default app to handle this type of files.

Comment: Netbeans is not in the list, and "add" button is not active. I have to choose a program first to be able to click on "add" button.

Comment: can't do this as I explained above. "add" bottun allow me only to choose an existing program from the list.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have to edit `netbean-8.1.desktop` file( in /usr/share/applications/ folder ), then change `Exec=/bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-8.1/bin/netbeans"` to `EExec=/bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-8.1/bin/netbeans" %F`. This help me get netbeans application in the list of programs.